# How to move back from tty to GUI in ubuntu version 22.04

Tags: command-line, gdm, tty

My ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS  after running sudo apt autoremove many thing from my ubuntu remove like ubuntu terminal and other applications so i press ctrl alt F12 them tty terminal opened I questioning to chat gpt it suggests me to run many command like gdm.service but error found like gdm.service not found and many command i runned in tty1 to tty6 but still not found error occur so kindly help me how i go Back to GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesson Learned: ALWAYS read your apt output before agreeing to a removal. That's why it is there -- so you can review and reject.

- An autoremoval can destroy your desktop if YOU installed the desktop manually using apt. The Ubuntu Desktop installer (.iso, LiveUSB) contains additional safeguards (apt-marking) to prevent exactly this kind of mass removal.

  This suggests that there might be more to the story than disclosed so far.

The easy way to restore your desktop environment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, which will automatically include all the other desktop packages.

If you want a list of removed packages so you can re-install each one, you will find the list in the apt history log: `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: Sir this command sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop run tty ? Is automatically GUI open after running this command

Comment: Yes - you'll need your tty terminal to issue that command. But I would - in your case - listen to the advice of @user535733 and install all those packages you readily allowed to be removed by using the `history.log`.

Comment: Permission denied msg received when /var/log/apt/history.log run command by the way i install again ubuntu- desktop so what i will do further for open GUI